# Php download image from html tag and return the downloaded image

Tags: php

please help me with the blow code on where am having error, i have two php function, one copies an external image from and website in any string that has [img]here is the image link[/img]. and the other function returns the image downloaded in our sever and set to the previous external link which was copied from.

here is the two functions

```
 function  covertContentToHTML($title, $content)
{
    $regex = '#\[img( alt="(.+?)\")?( caption="(.+?)\")?](.+?)\[\/img\]#is';
    $content = preg_replace_callback($regex, function ($matches) use ($title) {
        $imageAlt = $matches[2];
        $caption = $matches[4];
        $imageUrl = $matches[5];
        $caption = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $caption));
        $imageUrlToLocalPath = copyimage($imageUrl);
        return '<figure class="center"><img src="' . $imageUrlToLocalPath . '" alt="' . (empty($imageAlt) ? $title : $imageAlt) . '" title="' . $title . '">
        ' . (!empty($caption) ? '<br><figcaption><span class="help">Inset:</span> <strong>' . $caption . '</strong></figcaption>' : '') . '
        </figure>';
    }, $content);
    return $content;
}

    function copyimage($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('#<img(.*?)src="(.*?)"(.*?)>#is', '[img]\\2[/img]', $content);
    preg_match_all('#\[img( alt="(.+?)\")?( caption="(.+?)\")?](.+?)\[\/img\]#is', $content, $matches);
    $images = $matches[5];
    $i = 0;
    $im = [];
foreach ($images as $image) {
    array_push($im, $image);
    $i++;
    $encodeImageUrl = base64_encode($image);
    $imageBasename = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $imageLocalPath = "images/hsi/" . $encodeImageUrl . "/images";
    if ( !is_dir( $imageLocalPath ) ) {
        mkdir($imageLocalPath, 0755, true );
    }
    copy($image, $imageLocalPath.'/'.$imageBasename); 
}
}
```

the problem am having is that the function convertContentToHtml Does not return the downloaded image and set them to the return figure class..

example i have a string or content like this

```
$content = 'HELLO WORLD <p> [img]http://www.stackoverflow/images/newimage.jpg[/img] testing this content [img]http://www.stackoverflow.com/images/newimage2.jpg'[/img]';
```

the code function convertContentToHtml will download the the stackoverflow newimage.jpg and newimage2.jpg  to my server and then replace with the stackoverflow/images/newimage.jpg and stackoverflow.com/images/newimage2.jpg to to my link to the image downloaded using the copyimage function.

please help. thanks.

Comment: Please show code for the "convertContentToHtml", currently you only show code for `covertContentToHtml`. Also add info about what you found out when you where debugging your code. What is the problem with your code, do you get an error, which error?

Comment: Just before the foreach statement add `echo "IMAGES:"; var_dump($images);`, and look at an empty array.....

Comment: it returns an empty array of images while it was downloaded... i mean in the copyimage function

Comment: luuk i guess the images are returning empty array

Comment: Indeed, an empty array and what, in your opinion will happen in the function `copyimage` if `$content` is an empty array just before the `foreach` line?

Comment: SO is not about writing code for you, you have to do it yourself! I am just giving a hint on where to start you search to help you solve your problem....

Comment: please help me out and fix the error Luuk... am pleading.. am just having nightmare on that.. please